# What is the maximum number of columns can be created using single DF and DS?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Background - Soon in a month I am going to kick-start a project where the dataset has around 300 columns.

Question  - what is the maximum number of columns supported in Spark dataframe and dataset ?

Note - I am new to dataframe/dataset

Comment: in the big data world, there are many cases were storage is very cheap, but joins are very expensive, and it does make sense to keep very wide tables to avoid runtime joins

Comment: flagged 2018 comment as reading as "unkind" in 2023.  I don't think 1st comment to fairly new user (under 1k rep) should be "read the documentation".  I have 20 years of experience as professional dev and I can still be daunted by docs for frameworks I'm learning (esp. using for 1st time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had DFs that contained about 280 columns, and it worked without a problem.

For DSs, it's a bit more complicated.  there is 254 parameters limit in java, so you won't be able to construct a wider DS (because it is based of a java class).
If you have control of the structure of the data, I would recommend grouping columns into structs, it will allow you to overcome the 254 limitation, and make it much easier to work with (if you group the columns in a logical way)

also, make sure to store your data in a columnar format (like parquet), to take advantage of sparks predicate pushdown ability - it will improve you performance significantly when you are using such wide tables